# SQL Server - Sync 200 tables

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 server that contains a DB of about 200 tables.  I need to nightly sync those tables to other DB's on the same server.  The sync'ing would always be one way.  I'm hoping to avoid having a INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE statement for every table.  Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Log shipping might be possible on the same SQL Server instance.  Do the other DBs have exactly the same schema as the source?

Comment: All of the target tables are in the [dbo] schema.  The source tables have differing schemas.